# DataFactory Debug Error - BadRequest - factory is deleted

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating a pipeline that only runs a simple "wait ", just  for testing, because I am trying to understand why my others pipeline are returning errors (the same error).

When I try to debug, it sends the following error:

```json
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Operation could not be completed as factory is deleted",
    "target": "pipeline/Teste_ParaApagar/runid/f0e412a9-21a2-4d0f-ab28-c0287a484326",
    "details": null,
    "error": null
}
```

I searched everywhere, I can´t find answer. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: Is the ADF been deleted during the debug?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a common error.
According to the [policy](https://azure.microsoft.com/free/free-account-faq/), I think you should check your account to see if your ADF was disabled.